# Testing route wildcards with phpunit?

Tags: symfony, testing, routes, phpunit, wildcard

I have the following controller with a route which contains a wild card

```
    /**
     * @Route("api/1.0/test/{$a}", name="test", methods={"GET"})
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function testSimple(int $a)
    {
        return $this->json(['success' => ($a == 1) ? true : false]);
    }
```

And I am trying to test the it returns true if the wildcard $a = 1, however I do not seem to be able to find the right syntax to test the route :

A - as a full path, wildcard set as value to be passed :

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function checkRouteWildcardReturnsExepctedResult()
    {

        $client = $this->createClient();
        $request = $client->request('GET','api/1.0/test/1');

        $response = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
        $this->assertEquals(json_encode(["success" => true]), $response);

    }


Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'{"success":true}'
+'{"success":false,"errors":["No route found for GET \/api\/1.0\/test\/1"],"data":[]}'
```

B - specifying the route exactly, find the correct route, but $a is not set

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function checkRouteWildcardReturnsExepctedResult()
    {

        $client = $this->createClient();
        $request = $client->request('GET','api/1.0/test/{$a}',['a' => 1]);

        $response = $client->getResponse()->getContent();

        $this->assertEquals(json_encode(["success" => true]), $response);
    }


--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'{"success":true}'
+'{"success":false,"errors":["Could not resolve argument $a of [__CLASS__]::testSimple(), maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the controller.service_arguments?"],"data":[]}'
```

Any advice of link to some documentation I appear to not be able to find greatly appreciated - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, option 1 is the correct solution, and the route wildcard should not contain a $, should be `@Route("api/1.0/test/{a}", name="test", methods={"GET"})`

So it does work as I initially expected it to